# CodeName One Project - POST Request to Google Sheets throws 401 Error but GET is fine

Tags: java

I am working with CodeName One in for the first time building a simple app in Java that uses Google Sheets as a database. I have been having trouble getting CN1 to play nicely with Google Oauth2 authentication, so I decided to authenticate using a Google API Key.

GET requests work, but POST requests throw a 401 Error.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// Create variables to use in the ReSTful URL call
        String spreadsheetId = "1tZgq25yfhrsGz4MRb7QXQojYhYdUyZAvAh4VhUEsX0k";
        String apiKey = "AIzaSyChRaP0CJjlhp-T-k1aYzFNOOtuDMQX6kg";
        String range = "DogObjects!A1:C1";
        String rangeAppend = "DogObjects!A1:C1:append";

        // GET a range from a Google Spreadsheet
        ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest();
        r.setPost(false);
        //r.setUrl("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/"+spreadsheetId+"/values/"+range+"?majorDimension=COLUMNS");
        r.setUrl("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/"+spreadsheetId+"/values/"+range+"?majorDimension=COLUMNS&key="+apiKey);

        System.out.println(r.getUrl()); // Check to see if the request URL is as intended
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
        Map<String, Object> result = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(result); // Check to see what was in the response body
        //Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>)result.get("values");
        System.out.println(result.get("values"));

        // Append a range to a Google Spreadsheet - not yet working - appears to require Oauth2 authorization
        // First build a request body
        String str =    "{" +
                        "  \"range\":\"" + range + "\"," +
                        "  \"majorDimension\": \"COLUMNS\"," +
                        "  \"values\": [" + arrayStr +
                        "  \"values\": [[\"1\",\"3\",\"7\"]]," +
                       "}";
        // Then instantiate a connection object and make a POST request
        ConnectionRequest s = new ConnectionRequest();
        s.setPost(true);
        s.setUrl("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/"+spreadsheetId+"/values/"+rangeAppend+"?valueInputOption=RAW&key="+apiKey);
        //s.setUrl("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/"+spreadsheetId+"/values/"+rangeAppend+"?valueInputOption=RAW");
        s.setRequestBody(str);
        System.out.println(s.getRequestBody()); // See what is in the request body
        System.out.println(s.getUrl()); // See what the URL is like
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(s);
```

I have been working on this for days without success. I've some related posts online, but none with with answers that work and none that are using Java classes from CN1. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the google sheets API but here are some ideas that might help you on the way:

- The URL you used looks wrong. Normally a `POST` request shouldn't include `?` `GET` style arguments like you add to the URL. This might be wrong
- 401 is an "Unauthorized" error which means the `GET` operation might work as you have a read permission but you might be missing a write permission. I see an API key but I don't see an authorization key which is usually passed in an HTTP header.
- You can use the `setReadResponseForErrors(true)` method to get a detailed error message in the response body.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Shai. I realize you are right about passing arguments in a POST url. I've moved those to the request body, but still no joy. I will give the other issues my thoughts now. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, feel free to post another question if you are still stuck on this with up to date details.